# SQLAlchemy: Checking if model based on many-to-many relationship exists

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to store classes in Postgres with SQLAlchemy models, and before I store a new class, I want to check if a class with the same functions (with same args and kwargs) exist in the db. If it does, I just want to id for a foreign key to another model.

Currently I have BaseClass, ClassFunction, and their association models as:

```
class_function_assoc = Table('class_function_assocs', Base.metadata,
        Column('base_class_id', Integer, ForeignKey('base_classes.id')),
        Column('class_function_id', Integer, ForeignKey('class_functions.id'))
)

class BaseClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'base_classes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    class_name = Column(String)
    class_pickle = Column(PickleType, nullable=False)

    functions = relationship('ClassFunction',
                               secondary=class_function_assoc,
                               back_populates='base_classes')

class ClassFunction(Base):
    __tablename__  = 'class_functions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, index=True)
    args = Column(ARRAY(String))
    kwargs = Column(JSON)

    base_classes = relationship('BaseClass',
                                 secondary=class_function_assoc,
                                 back_populates='functions')
```

Say I have a new class that I want to consider storing:

```
class TempClass():

    def func1(arg1):
        pass

    def func2(arg1, kwarg1=value1):
        pass
```

But how do I query the database to check if this class already exists?

I would like to join the tables together and only return a match if the functions are exactly the same.

I've gotten as far as:

```
q = (s.query(BaseClass)
.filter_by(class_name='TempClass')
.join(class_function_assoc)
.join(ClassFunction)
.filter(or_(
        and_(ClassFunction.name=='func1', args==['arg1']),
        and_(ClassFunction.name=='func2', args==['arg1'], kwargs={'kwarg1':'value1'})
)))
```

Which actually does return a result, but since it's using `or_` it will match if only one function matches, which is not what I'm looking for.

Maybe I need to query and then process the result in Python instead? Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the `or_` expression? Can you try to use multiple `filter` (i.e. `and`) instead? `s.query(..).filter(..).join(..).filter(ClassFunction.name == ..).filter(ClassFunction.name ==..)`

Comment: First thing to understand is that you need to find _multiple_ DB records, one for each function. For that you need to produce as many subqueries as there are functions involved, correlate them with a main query for the class, and use [`exists()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/selectable.html?highlight=implicit_returning#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists) for each subquery in the condition clause of the main query.

Comment: @9000 that sounds reasonable. Would you happen to have an example of something similar?